# Efficient way to add variables and constraints through Gurobi Python without enumerating through all elements

Tags: python, loops, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am learning to build optimization models through Gurobi python and I am having some issues finding the pythonic way of defining decision variables and constraints:

Assuming I have these sets:

```
time={morning, afternoon, evening};
interval={early,late};
food={burger, banana, apple, orange};
```

and my decision variable is binary eat[time,interval,food]. However I only have a defined set of possible options as below and cannot enumerate all elements of my sets:

```
time      interval  food  number  value
morning   early   banana   2      500
morning   early   apple    3      600
afternoon early   burger   1      800
evening    late   orane    2      400
```

so my eat variables can only be the following:

```
eat[morning,early,banana]
eat[morning,early,apple]
eat[afternoon,early,burger]
eat[evening,late,orange]
```

and I cannot do:

```
eat = m.addVars(time, interval, food, name = "Eat", vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

I can do something like:

```
eat = {}
for row in input.to_dict('records'):
         key = (row['time'], row['interval'],row['food'])
         eat[key] =  m.addVar(name = "Eat", vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

But I still have trouble defining my objective which is multiplying number and value and eat and I am looking for a more consistent, elegant way:

```
obj = quicksum(number[i,j,k]*value[i, j, k] * eat[i, j, k] for i in time 
for j in interval for k in food)
```

The above will enumerate all which is wrong and I tried something like this:

```
obj = quicksum(number[key]*value[key] * eat[key] \
                 for key in eat)
```

which limits it to only defined combinations in the dictionary but then I am struggling with constraints when I have to separate elements of dictionary like below:

```
m.addConstrs(quicksum(eat[i,j,k] for k in food)==1 for i in time for j in interval)
```

or something like

```
m.addConstrs(quicksum(eat[morning,j,banana] ==1) for j in interval)
```

Sorry for the long questions. Any help from optimization/python experts would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help you to make use of the [tupledict](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/py_tupledict.html) structure the Gurobi Python API has to store the variables. It has some convenient methods which allow you to sum, multiply or slice variables easily. I provide a complete example below.

```
from gurobipy import GRB, Model
import numpy as np

tuples = [('morning', 'early', 'banana'),('morning', 'early', 'apple'), 
('afternoon', 'early', 'burger'), ('evening', 'late', 'orane')]

numbers, values = [2, 3, 1, 2], [500, 600, 800, 400]

m = Model('SO52451928')

eat = m.addVars(tuples, name='eat', vtype=GRB.BINARY)

coeffs = np.array(numbers) * np.array(values) # Can be made with regular lists as well
coeffs = dict(zip(tuples, coeffs))

obj = eat.prod(coeffs)
m.setObjective(obj)

# This structure holds the unique combinations of (time, interval) that 
# appear in the data. They are necessary, because they form the set over which
# our constraints are defined
time_intervals = set(zip(*zip(*tuples)[:2]))

constrs = m.addConstrs((
    eat.sum(i, j, '*') == 1 for i, j in time_intervals), name='one_food')

m.write(m.ModelName+'.lp')
m.optimize()

if m.SolCount > 0:
    print(zip(m.getAttr(
    'VarName', m.getVars()), m.getAttr('x', m.getVars())))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This was great help.

Comment: how would you address constraints like these `m.addConstrs(quicksum(eat[morning,j,banana] ==1) for j in interval)`, creating another structure like time_intervals?

Comment: If you would like to express that for each time and food combination you need exactly one interval then yes, it is necessary to extract the unique time x food combinations. It becomes somewhat more verbose though: `set(zip(zip(*tuples)[0], zip(*tuples)[2]))`